# Как узнать вошел admin в backend yii2?

Tags: yii2, frontend, backend

Мне нужно скрывать кое какие элементы во frontend если админ не вошел в админку. Как можно определить во frontend, вошел ли пользователь в backend? Кто знает?

Comment: Вы хотите узнать залогинился ли какой-либо пользователь с правами администратора на сайте?

Comment: Если человек зашёл в админку, значит авторизовался. Раз он авторизовался, значит у него есть назначенная роль. Раз у него есть роль, то наверняка у админа эта роль админ. Проверяй её

Comment: Да. Залогинился ли кто-то в backend из frontend'а

Если залогиниться в админку, то если попытаться вывести Yii::$app->user->isGuest во frontend, то будет выведено true, т.е. пользователь гость. Пользователь будет не гость в backend'е, т.к. он авторизовался там

Comment: Yii::$app разные в front и в back приложениях. Т.е. если ты залогинился в одном из них, в другом приложении ты не залогинен. Вот мне нужно узнать из одного из приложений, залогинился ли пользователь в другом приложении.

Comment: Никто не знает?((

Comment: Ребята?????((((

Comment: @Сергей, Алексей выше вам уже указал, что надо делать (проверять роль залогиненного пользователя-посетителя). Если у вас проблемы с облачением этого в код, дополните вопрос.

Comment: Всё что мне написал это очевидно. МНе нужно узнать из FRONTEND залогинился ли кто-то в BACKEND. Уже несколько раз это написал. Если написать Yii::$app->user, то это будет пользователь для того приложения в котором его вызвали. Мне же нужно узнать пользователя из другого приложения

Comment: Может можно как-то вызвать Yii::$backend->user или как-то еще)

Comment: Хорошо помогают тут людям...

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в таблицу пользователя поле lastLogin (timeStamp), а в layout бакэнда добавь вызов функции, которая будет обновлять это поле.

А в фронтенде проверяй, прошло ли на пример 5 минут с момента указанного в поле lastLogin, если нет будем считать что админ онлайн.